# Commit and push to GitHub pull request branch from Azure Pipelines

Tags: git, github, azure-pipelines, github-api

I have an Azure Pipeline [[source](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/master/server/azure-pipelines.migrate.yaml), [runs](https://dev.azure.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/_build?definitionId=26&_a=summary)] triggered by pull request. I am following [this GitHub guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork) to commit to the contributor's branch used to create the pull request.

In order to do that, I have disabled the default Pipelines `checkout` step:

```yaml
steps:
  - checkout: none
```

I am then trying to clone the contributor's repository and checkout their branch used for the pull request.

```yaml
steps:
  ...

  - script: |
      git clone $(System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryUri) .
      git checkout $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)
    displayName: checkout source branch
```

However, `System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryUri` is returning the git URI of *my* repository, not the contributor's.

My primary repository:

- `https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists.git`

Variables I have tried using (see [here](https://dev.azure.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/_build/results?buildId=2781&view=logs&j=12f1170f-54f2-53f3-20dd-22fc7dff55f9&t=76467409-274e-589c-5c88-4286504c504b&l=12)):

- `System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI`:
  `https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists.git`
- `Build.Repository.Uri`: `https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists`

I think I need a predefined variable in a build Pipeline that can give me either of the following:

- `https://github.com/<GitHubUsernameOfPrContributor>/FilterLists.git`
- `<GitHubUsernameOfPrContributor>`

How can I clone the pull request contributor's repository and checkout their branch used for the pull request? An answer may be a solution to any of the following:

- Is there another [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops) that I missed that contains the contributor's repository URI or GitHub username?
- Can I tweak the Azure Pipelines [`checkout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#checkout) task to checkout the branch from the other contributor's repository instead of my own? In order to configure the fork as a [Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-repositories), it seems like I would need the contributor's fork URI or username.
- Can I get this URI from the GitHub API directly somehow?
- Is there some other solution? It seems I am making this more difficult than it should be...

**UPDATE**: Also [requested on Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/916468/add-predefined-variable-for-github-pull-request-co.html). Upvotes there appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to get what I need by calling the GitHub API from my Pipeline. A predefined variable from Azure Pipelines would be preferred, but this will work for now.

```yaml
  - bash: |
      FORKURI=$(curl -X GET "https://api.github.com/repos/$BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME/pulls/$SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTNUMBER" | jq -r '.head.repo.clone_url')
      git clone "$FORKURI" .
      git checkout "$SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEBRANCH"
    displayName: checkout source branch
```